# Sqlite how to select case for multiple values in a column

Tags: sqlite

So, I have this table:

```
id|otherid|key|value
--------------------
1  1       ak  av
2  1       bk  bv
3  2       ak  av
3  2       ak  av2
```

The things to note is that other ids are repeating and they can have same keys with values multiple times. The thing I want to retrieve would be the value for the key, or, if there are multiple values for same key some string.
So, I'd like to receive for otherids

```
otherid|key|value
-----------------
1       ak  av
1       bk  bv
2       ak  SEQUENCE
```

Where 'SEQUENCE' string allows me to know that there are multiple values for the single key for otherid. What query would accomplish this?

Comment: Do you really need the "SEQUENCE" string? Would another column with the count of values suffice?

Comment: Yeah, this will be shown in GUI, I want db to do most of the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get one output row for multiple input rows, use grouping.

The count of rows in the group is available with `COUNT(*)`; you can handle the cases with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
SELECT otherid,
       key,
       CASE COUNT(*)
       WHEN 1 THEN MIN(value)
       ELSE        'SEQUENCE'
       END AS value
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY otherid,
         key;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
otherid,key,
(SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(value)=1 THEN value
      WHEN COUNT(value)=0 THEN '*nil*'
      ELSE '*sequence*'
    END)
FROM datasingle
WHERE otherid=myid GROUP BY key;
```